# Looping through values from other database using the ID (primary key) with datatool (using expl3?)

Tags: expl3, loops, datatool

I have set up a database structure for projects and people. The aim is to have the IDs of the people as a value stored in a column of the project database.
Now I would like to refer to the people, whose information is stored in a different database.

### UPDATE

I was able to get the desired information using `\DTLgetvalue`. This works now fine for one entry in `pi`. But how can I loop through all of the entries stored in `pi`?
My attempt with `clist_map_inline` fails.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{datatool}
% ===== people database setup =======
\makeatletter
\define@key{person}{name}{\DTLnewdbentry{\crcDB}{name}{#1}}
\define@key{person}{nameFirst}{\DTLnewdbentry{\crcDB}{nameFirst}{#1}}
\makeatother
\NewDocumentCommand{\crcPersonEntry}{ m m }{
  \def\crcDB{#1}
  \DTLifdbexists{\crcDB}{}{\DTLnewdb{\crcDB}}
  \DTLnewrow{\crcDB}
  \setkeys{person}{#2}
}

% ===== project database setup
\makeatletter
\define@key{project}{name}[\DTLnewdbentry{\crcDB}{name}{}]{\DTLnewdbentry{\crcDB}{name}{#1}}
\define@key{project}{pi}[\DTLnewdbentry{\crcDB}{pi}{}]{\DTLnewdbentry{\crcDB}{pi}{#1}}
\makeatother
\NewDocumentCommand{\crcProjectEntry}{ m m }{
  \def\crcDB{#1}
  \DTLifdbexists{\crcDB}{}{\DTLnewdb{\crcDB}}
  \DTLnewrow{\crcDB}
  \setkeys{project}{#2}
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% Use: \getProject{<id>}

\NewDocumentCommand{\getPIs}{m}{%
\clist_map_inline:Nn {#1}{%
  \DTLgetvalue{\thePI}{##1}{1}{\dtlcolumnindex{##1}{nameFirst}}\thePI\space
  \DTLgetvalue{\thePI}{##1}{1}{\dtlcolumnindex{##1}{name}}\thePI
}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\getProject}{m}{%
  \DTLgetvalue{\theProjectName}{#1}{1}{\dtlcolumnindex{#1}{name}}\theProjectName-\space
  \DTLgetvalue{\thePIlist}{#1}{1}{\dtlcolumnindex{#1}{pi}}(\thePIlist)\space
\getPIs{\thePIlist}
}

 \ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
\crcProjectEntry{project1}{
  name={My Project},
  pi={person1, person2}
}
\crcProjectEntry{project2}{
  name={My other Project},
  pi={person3}
}

\crcPersonEntry{person1}{
  name={Perssonos},
  nameFirst={Peter}
}

\crcPersonEntry{person2}{
  name={Holgersson},
  nameFirst={Agnes}
}

\crcPersonEntry{person3}{
  name={Ickstein},
  nameFirst={Paula}
}



%\getProject{project1} % --> My Project, Peter Perssonos, Agnes Holgersson

\getProject{project2} % -> My other Project, Paula Ickstein

\end{document}
```

That is the current result.

[image]

Comment: Try printing out `thePIList` just before the clist_map_inline command to see what are the content/catcode.

Comment: I get the content of the key "pi", e.g. 'person1, person2'  or 'person3'. So it seems the content is passed correctly to the macro "\getPIs". Any suggestions how to solve it?

Comment: So if you already have the value `person3` how would you manually "loop through the values"? (I'm not familiar with datatool)

Comment: Using `\tl_analysis_show:n` for the argument of `\getPIs` I get: `The token list contains the tokens:
>  \thePIlist (control sequence=macro:->person1, person2).`. Looping through the values is only necessary when I have more than one value (e.g. `person1, person2` in the database `project1`. In that case the names of the people behind `person1` and `person2` should be printed.

Comment: Try printing out the `##1` (don't run datatool to get the name yet, just print out `##1`) to see whether the clist is parsed correctly.

Comment: Yes, that prints the items correctly (as expected): `person1 person2`.

Comment: Hm, but if you pass directly `person1` into `DTLgetvalue` you get correct result? Try the analysis_show one to see if there's any spurious character.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135002/discussion-between-lukascb-and-user202729).

Comment: Do you *need* to use `datatool`?

Comment: I guess technically it is not necessary. But I use `datatool` at various places in the document. But I am open to a different (more stable?) solution with the MWE above. I thought it would only be possible with `datatool` especially regarding the key-value macros.