# How to change the delimiter for last item using datatool?

Tags: lists, datatool

This is a follow up question on two other questions I am struggeling with:

- [How to change the delimiter for a final item in a clist?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/639801/how-to-change-the-delimiter-for-a-final-item-in-a-clist?noredirect=1#comment1594719_639801)
- [Looping through values from other database using the ID (primary key) with datatool (using expl3?)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/637989/looping-through-values-from-other-database-using-the-id-primary-key-with-datat)

A couple of things I could figure out, but I still struggle with the final delimiter and displaying more than one name.

### Update

With changing to `datatool` completely I was able to get it *almost* done. But still after the second item I get `,\space` which is not wanted. It works smoothly for one entry:

[image]

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\PIsList}{ m }{%
  \DTLforeach*{PI}{\id=ID}{%
    \expandafter\DTLifinlist\expandafter{\id}{#1}%
    {\DTLgetvalueforkey{\thePIname}{name}{PI}{ID}{\id}\thePIname\DTLiflastrow{}{,\space}}
    {}%
}}
```

complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{datatool,xspace}
% ===== people database setup =======
\makeatletter
\define@key{person}{name}{\DTLnewdbentry{\crcDB}{name}{#1}}
\define@key{person}{ID}{\DTLnewdbentry{\crcDB}{ID}{#1}}
\makeatother

% ===== project database setup
\makeatletter
\define@key{project}{ID}{\DTLnewdbentry{\crcDB}{ID}{#1}}
\define@key{project}{pi}{\DTLnewdbentry{\crcDB}{pi}{#1}}
\makeatother

% Load entries into databases
\NewDocumentCommand{\crcEntry}{ o m m }{%
  \def\crcDB{#2}%
  \DTLifdbexists{\crcDB}{}{\DTLnewdb{\crcDB}}%
  \DTLnewrow{\crcDB}%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}{\setkeys{#2}{#3}}{\setkeys{#1}{#3}}%
}


\NewDocumentCommand{\PIsList}{ m }{%
  \DTLforeach*{PI}{\id=ID}{%
    \expandafter\DTLifinlist\expandafter{\id}{#1}%
    {\DTLgetvalueforkey{\thePIname}{name}{PI}{ID}{\id}\thePIname\DTLiflastrow{}{,\space}}
    {}%
}}


\NewDocumentCommand{\crcProPI}{ m }{%
   \DTLgetvalueforkey{\projectPIsList}{pi}{project}{ID}{#1}%
    \textbf{%
     #1\space%
      (\PIsList{\projectPIsList})}\xspace%
}
% in case someone misspelled the command
% this is just a fallback
\let\crcpropi\crcProPI



\begin{document}

\crcEntry[project]%<-- keyset
{project}%<-- databse
{%
  ID={A01},
  pi={person1,person2}
}
\crcEntry[project]%<-- keyset
{project}%<-- databse
{%
  ID={A02},
  pi={person3}
}

\crcEntry[person]{PI}{%
  ID = {person1},
  name={Perssonos},
}

\crcEntry[person]{PI}{%
  ID = {person2},
  name={Holgersson},
}

\crcEntry[person]{PI}{%
  ID = {person3},
  name={Ickstein},
}



\crcpropi{A01} % --> A01 (Perssonos, Holgersson)

\crcpropi{A02} % -> A02 (Ickstein)

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/108731/98739 I was able to adapt:

```
\newcommand*{\uniquePI}{}

\NewDocumentCommand{\PIsList}{ m }{%
  \DTLforeach*{PI}{\id=ID}{%
    \expandafter\DTLifinlist\expandafter{\id}{#1}%
    {\DTLgetvalueforkey{\thePIname}{name}{PI}{ID}{\id}%
    \ifdefempty{\uniquePI}%
    {\let\uniquePI\thePIname}% first element of list
    {% append to list
      \eappto\uniquePI{,\space\thePIname}%
    }}
    {}%
}\uniquePI}
```

[image]

Same result can be achieved using `expl3`-Syntax (credits go to `gusbrs` (see comments):

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\PIsList}{ m }
{
  \seq_clear:N \l_tmpa_seq
  \DTLforeach*{PI}{\id=ID}
  {
    \exp_args:Nx \DTLifinlist {\id}{#1}
    {
      \DTLgetvalueforkey{\thePIname}{name}{PI}{ID}{\id}
      \seq_put_left:NV \l_tmpa_seq \thePIname
    }
    {}
  }
  \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { ,~ }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Comment: Ah, you figured out the `datatool` part, which I don't know well. Now that you did, you can try `\NewDocumentCommand{\PIsList}{ m } {\seq_clear:N \l_tmpa_seq \DTLforeach*{PI}{\id=ID} {\exp_args:Nx \DTLifinlist {\id}{#1} {\DTLgetvalueforkey{\thePIname}{name}{PI}{ID}{\id} \seq_put_left:NV \l_tmpa_seq \thePIname} {}} \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { ,~ }}`

Comment: Wow, your solution is about 1 sec quicker compiling the document. you should post it as an answer as well.

Comment: Please feel free to include it in yours, you did the hard part.  ;-)

Comment: The only issue I have now is the sorting of the names, they are according to their appearence in the database (row) and not in the field `pi`. But that is something due to `datatool`...

Comment: You can sort that sequence. See `\seq_sort:Nn` in `texdoc interface3`. (Though probably not trivial if non-ascii characters are involved, which I guess might be the case...).

Comment: hm, thanks for pointing out to the documentation, but `\seq_sort:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {\sort_return_same: }` is not working (or it is working, but not how I want it to be...)

Comment: That would just leave the sequence unchanged, if that's what you mean by "not working". You must have different cases, where eventually `\sort_return_swapped:` might also be called.